# How to allow "potentially dangerous" parameter values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've got a Web API project.  One of my endpoints allows a string search, which could contain special characters.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Search")]
[ValidateInput(false)] // this is *supposed* to allow us to search using "unsafe" characters, like %, & etc.
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    ...
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{searchValue}", Name = "GenericSearch")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Search(string searchValue)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I call `api/Search/fred`, this works as expected.

When I call `api/Search/fred%25`, I get this error:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (%).]
>      System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig() +561
>      System.Web.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context) +54

This is despite the fact that my controller is decorated with `[ValidateInput(false)]`, and based on other answers I found elsewhere, I added `requestValidationMode` to my Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

What other secret switch do I need to flip?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's only for MVC. But only on my phone ATM. Would also say if its not just MVC then have you tried it on the method instead if the class?

Comment: According to the answer of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967103/a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client try to put it in the query string

Comment: @AndrewHarris AFAIK, isn't WebAPI a derivative of MVC, just with a few different controllers and things bolted on?

Comment: @GeoffJames http://stackoverflow.com/q/9698224/7077113

Comment: @AndrewHarris Ah, cool. Must be one of the things bolted on. Good to know, thanks :)

Comment: @GeoffJames all good I think that confirmed.s my suspicion though, you need the attribute at the method level if I read it correctly.

Comment: Are you missing the attribute on `httpRuntime` for allowing the Invalid Characters? `<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

Comment: @AndrewHarris Best check with Shaul - he's the OP

Comment: @AndrewHarris I just tried putting the attribute at the method level.  No difference.

Comment: Then as Mark C said, you're missing the invalid chars attribute.

Comment: @MarkC. Take yourself a prize.  That fixed it.  But what do I do if I don't want to remove validation on all endpoints, just the ones I specify?

Comment: @ShaulBehr  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6025522/getting-a-potentially-dangerous-request-path-value-was-detected-from-the-client

Comment: @ViswasMenon please can you be more explicit about what you find of interest at that question?

Comment: @ShaulBehr The solution for that question should solve the issue that you have as well.<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false" />
</system.web>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: @Alejandro not a duplicate.  The question is different and the answer given is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the attribute on httpRuntime for allowing the Invalid Characters.

```
<httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a way to do it so that I don't remove validation on all endpoints, just the ones I specify?  And does the `[ValidateInput(false)]` do anything at all?

Comment: Only on my phone at the moment give me a min

Comment: Found it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9698482/7850): use a `location` element to confine the settings to urls under that path.  If you'd like to update your answer with that, I'll give you answer credit.

Comment: And for those who are interested, `[ValidateInput(false)]` has no effect whatsoever.

Comment: Nice! Good find